# Remove textbox when field is empty

Tags: rdlc

I'm trying to hide a textbox when the field is empty, but it's not working:

```
IIf(IsNothing(First(Fields!Fld27.Value, "P2BDataSet")),true,False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the text box visibility property

```
iif(Fields!YouField.Value>0, false, true)
```

If you still you did not get what you want, check [How to Hide RDLC Textbox Based on Value](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/how-to-hide-rdlc-textbox-based-on-value/)

Comment: space is still there, i want to remove this space @K Naga mallesh

Comment: If you're using Table/Tablix you have to set Visibility property of your TABLEROW.